# Formulating REST API call

Tags: api, rest, http, url, meetup

Here is my query string

`https://api.meetup.com/2/open_events?country=us&state=ca&city=sanfrancisco&category=34&page=10&group_photo&sign=true&&sign=true`

I'm having no success reaching the group_photo resource.

[In the docs](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/open_events/#response) they say:

> **group_photo**
>
> Returned when fields request parameter contains "group_photo".
>   Represents photo for the group hosting the event

I tried changing `group_photo` to `group_photo=true` but that didn't help.

[Here's the console if you wanna test it](https://secure.meetup.com/meetup_api/console/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Meetup API documentation](http://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/docs/2/open_events/):

> fields: Request that additional fields (separated by commas) be
>   included in the output

and

> group_photo: Returned when fields request parameter contains
>   "group_photo". Represents photo for the group hosting the event

so you must add `fields=group_photo` and the call you gave above would be be something like:

```
https://api.meetup.com/2/open_events?country=us&state=ca&city=sanfrancisco&category=34&page=10&fields=group_photo&sign=true&sign=true
```